# QApplication constructor segfault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

Earlier in the day, every thing worked nice as hell, suddenly it all broke.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app {argc, argv};
}
```

Compile with `g++ main.cpp -lQtCore -lQtGui -I/usr/include/qt4`, gives me a segfault, and I have no clue why.

I have made some investigation on the matter, and it seems that something may be wrong with either `argc` or `argv`, but earlier in the day this didn't happen at all.

Comment: "but earlier in the day this didn't happen" then, of course, you used `git bisect` (or a similar tool, of your version control system of choice) to figure out what change between "then" and "now" broke the build - right?

Comment: sadly, i haven't committed all day long, so i'm afraid i don't have that option

Comment: Nothing in your posted (trivial) program explains a segfault. There *must* be something you are not showing us.

Comment: i swear to god that's the most minimal example that reproduces the segfault, i swear. i'm as stumbled as you are

Comment: What's the debugger showing? What happens when you break into the segfault?

Comment: @ChemiCalChems commit early, commit often (one can always rewrite (local) history) ;-)

Comment: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=<optimized out>, lazy=0, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=662856, reladdr=<optimized out>, map=0x7ffff7ff64c8) at do-rel.h:112
112 do-rel.h: No such file or directory.`

Comment: do you use a build system, Qt usually uses some more compiler flags

Comment: I'd normally use cmake, in fact, for my project I do. But for the minimal example I haven't.

Comment: No need to panic guys, upgrade to Qt5 after realising I was using Qt4 and the problem fixed itself. Thanks a lot for the help. Will answer own question when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Qt5 from Qt4 solved the problem.

Comment: It would be very useful, and a great documentation, if you can make additional notes about why it failed in Qt4.

Comment: Sadly, I have no clue whatsoever. It started failing and then on updating it stopped. I'd love to know myself.

Comment: Did you have Qt5 installed when running the Qt4 failing code? Maybe you had a mixed linking between Qt4 and Qt5.

Comment: While possible, I doubt it. I was running Qt4 for all yesterday, and then at 11PM it broke, I have no clue why.

Comment: @cbuchart It's worse than I thought, check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918095/qt4-applications-segfaulting-on-startup).